# ¿Como puedo optimizar este observer para que me funcione con varios elementos en react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

hola estoy empezando a estudiar react y estoy en proceso de hacer un lazy load ya logre obtenr el efecto deseado pero quisiera saber como podria optimizar la funcion para que funciones con todos los componentes el codigo es el siguiente:

```
export const Pages = () => {
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
const skillVisibility = () => {
    if (visible) {
        const classObserver = 'visibleObserver'
        return (
            <VisibilityObserver onVisibleChange={setVisible} obj={<Skill classObserve={classObserver}></Skill>} ></VisibilityObserver>
        )
    }else{
        const classObserver = 'hiddenObserver'
        return (
            <VisibilityObserver onVisibleChange={setVisible} obj={<Skill classObserve={classObserver}></Skill>} ></VisibilityObserver>
        )   
    }
}
return (
    <>
        <Presentation></Presentation>
        {skillVisibility()}
    </>
)
```

}

Comment: Un custom hook, ¿Porque pasas un componente como propiedad a otro?¿Tiene alguna ventaja/utilidad?

Comment: Bueno mi objetivo es hace un lazy load como explique arriba al ser varios componentes ya que cada uno es una sección de la página fue una de las soluciones que conseguí, pero solo hay dos problemas 1ero no se si será una buena práctica o no he estado investigando y no encuentro nada referente, 2do cómo te fijas al pasar el componente como tal al custom Hook no consigo la forma de reutilizar la función para los demás componentes y no quiero hacer varias funciones que van a hacer la misma función